# error when scafolding controller mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi when i try adding a controller using the controller actions and entity framework, it gives me an error saying:

> "there was an error with the selected code generator: unable to
>   retrieve metadata for 'Music.Model.Customer'. one or more validation
>   errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Music.Data.Customer : EntityType 'Customer' has no key defined. Define
>   the key for this entity type.
>
> Images: EntityType:EntitySet 'images' is based on type 'Customer that
>   has no keys defined.

I did build my context before adding the controller

Comment: Does `Customer` have a key value defined?

Comment: No it didn't, Ive just added a key and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your model, you should decorate a property with the `[Key]` attribute. For example:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    ...
    ...

}
```

Entity Framework will recognise the primary key of a table if the column is named Id. If your table does not have a primary key field named Id, you can identify the primary key field by setting the `[Key]` attribute.